# Threads are destroyed?

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, destroy

I create a pool of threads with an `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`, but after a time I noticed that some of them stoped to answer (call this method below).

They was destroyed? I doing synchonization and the system continues when all threads set that finished the task, but with this, the system enter in deadlock.

They was destroyed? What can I do to prevent or handle this?

```
//this is the method that threads call when finish the work
synchronized void setTaskFinish(){
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " finishing the work.");        
    finishedThreads++;  
    System.out.println(finishedThreads +" finished the work.");
    if(finishedThreads == numberThreads){            
        finishedThreads = 0;
        this.notify();
    }
}

//this is the method that creates the thread
//I dont know much about this executors yet, so I think it have errors
public void execute(int numberThreads) {    
    for (int i = 0; i < numberThreads; i++) {
        crawlers.add(new SlaveCrawler());
    }

    ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberThreads);        

    for (int i = 0, n = crawlers.size(); i < n; i++) {
        threadExecutor.execute((Runnable) crawlers.get(i));
    }      

    threadExecutor.shutdown();        
}
```

**EDIT**: I changed entirely my logic. I have not done much testing, but everything seems ok now. Maybe it was something wrong in my old logic.

Comment: It sounds like you may have a deadlock in your code, or some other problem. A short but complete program which demonstrates the problem would really help...

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "stopped to answer". Either all the threads in the thread-pool are busy, and can't perform more work - or **your** code have created a deadlock in your program. The thread pool might start and stop thread at its own leisure, but that's nothing you need to be concerned about. You should post some of the code.

Comment: Example: I working with 60 threads. The execution goes normal, but at certain point, only 55 threads set the task finished. The activity in program stopped. I suppose that they was destroyed, but I don't know if this occurs. If occurs, it's an error in my code, else I will fount another type of solution.

Comment: Which class does `setTaskFinish()` appear in? And why are you calling `notify()`?

Comment: setTaskFinish() is in the MasterCrawler. I have ONE MasterCrawler that get links to visit and distribute to SlaveCrawlers. When a slave finishs, them set they task finished. When all finishes, then notify the MasterCrawler to get new links.

Comment: If you're writing a web crawler , it's very easy to get stuck on network I/O - you should insert some debugging to see if that's what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executor won't destroy threads that are busy executing your tasks. If you assigned 60 tasks, and only 55 "complete" (more precisely, your `setTaskFinish()` method is only invoked 55 times), it could be an exception terminating your task prematurely. Deadlock is another possibility, but not the first I would examine.

What happens when your task throws an unchecked exception like `RuntimeException`? Does it call `setTaskFinish()` from a `finally` block? Why are you managing concurrency using `synchronized` instead of an `AtomicInteger`?

Comment: +1 for the answer, but I would use a CountDownLatch to control counting and "releasing"

Comment: Yes, it's not clear whether he's really signaling another thread (via `notify()`) to proceed, or just counting threads. If the former, a latch would be easiest to use.

Comment: I never heard of AtomicInteger. What is this? And I don't calling setTaskFinish() in finally block, but I dont see any exceptions. Anyway, I changed all this, so I need run new tests to determine if the threads still "disappearing".